# Database Views to simulate normalised tables from a single denormalised one

Tags: sql-server, view, database-normalization

We have a report store with a denormalised flat table that stores identical data to a multi-table model in a different database.

Flat table (example):

```
| col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | timestamp |
|-------|-------|-------|-----------|
| val1  | val2  | val3  | 1/1/1990  |
| val1  | val9  | val3  | 1/1/1990  |
```

In multiple tables:

```
| id1 | id2 | timestamp |
|-----|-----|-----------|
| 001 | 111 | 1/1/1990  |
| 001 | 112 | 1/1/1990  |

| id1 | col 1 | col 3 |
|-----|-------|-------|
| 001 | val1  | val3  |

| id2 | col 2 |
|-----|-------|
| 111 | val2  |
| 112 | val9  |
```

There are several old reporting queries that we would like to port over to the new flat table without having to rewrite them all up front - there are many of them and they are complex.

Is there a way of writing Views that can simulate a set of relational tables from the single flat table, so that the old reporting queries work without modification?

Comment: what means 'denormalized'? not in the 1st.? not in the 5ht? Can you provide some data?

Comment: @inetphantom edited to add detail

Comment: What is the key in the flat table? col1 & col3? Because if you do not have an ID, you will not be able to **directly** create a view out of it, means you would have to make a table with the information to make your `id`out of the natural Key

Comment: I'm afraid the architectural details haven't been worked out yet - this is still at the design stage.

Comment: Not all DBMS can make changes on Views. I would highly recomand you to rewrite those old reporting queries. Otherwise I see only "dirty" solutions to suround that. If you ony need the information by `SELECT`, you can make views.

Comment: Yes, I only need the information by `SELECT`.

Comment: To the downvoter - why the downvote? Can I improve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HereI create *dynamical* IDs. You could also initialy make that table with fix keys, and always when adding or removing a row in the flattable do the same with  the key here. Otherwise instead of Groub by use the `OVER` statement.

```
CREATE VIEW multitabkey AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() as key, col1, col3
FROM flattable
Group by col1, col3
```

**WARNING: those keys are not persistent:** if you delete the first row, all others get their id one smaler than before. You have *dynamic* IDs, but they are *consistnet*.

If you have a translation for your Keys you can use them as following:

```
CREATE VIEW multitabone AS
SELECT f.timestamp
FROM flattable as f
JOIN multitabkey as m ON m.col1 = f.col1 AND m.col3 = f.col3
Group by col1, col3
```

I assumed col1 , col2 are together a natural key.

**As mentioned, this is a workaround, your DB is not in 3rd normalform what can cause inconsistency.**

Comment: on Oracle and Mysql it is `ROWNUM`, this is by microsoft.

Comment: Will `ROW_NUMBER` make the rows match up even if the two views are selected with different `WHERE` clauses? They will need to be joined as if they were the original tables.

Comment: I am not shure about that, you will have to try or post it as a new question here on SO

Comment: @inetphantom: ROW_NUMBER() is a standard SQL analytic function. [Oracle supports it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm). ROWNUM is a different thing.